# Preg_match exclude word from text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have string:

> FirstWord word2 word3 wrongWord word4 lastWord

Want to select string starts with `FirstWord`, ends with `lastWord` and doesn't contain `wrongWord`.

For first and last I have:

> /firstword (.*?) lastword/i

but excluding `wrongword` didn't work.

Tried:

> /firstword (^wrongWord*?) lastword/i
>
> /firstword ^((?!wrongWord).)* lastword/i

and more like this, but nothing works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's wrong with simply the following?

```
/^firstword ((?:(?!wrongword).)+) lastword$/i
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/gJ9zZ1)

Regular expression:

```
^              the beginning of the string
 firstword     'firstword '
 (             group and capture to \1:
  (?:          group, but do not capture (1 or more times)
   (?!         look ahead to see if there is not:
    wrongword  'wrongword'
   )           end of look-ahead
   .           any character except \n
  )+           end of grouping
 )             end of \1
 lastword      ' lastword'
$              before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick:

```
/^firstword ((?:[^w]+?|\Bw|w(?!rongword\b))*?) lastword$/i
```

or more efficient:

```
/^firstword ((?>[^w\s]++|\s(?!lastword$)|\Bw|w(?!rongword\b))*+) lastword$/i
```

Comment: Nice, I haven't seem this pattern before but it looks pretty neat.

Comment: What's wrong with just `/^firstword(?:(?!wrongword).)+lastword$/i`, See [here](http://regex101.com/r/bE6sQ1)

Comment: not sure if it matters to OP, but if your wrongword was say `own`, this pattern would not match sentences containing the words `down`,`frowning`,etc..

Comment: @hwnd: This kind of pattern is not very efficient since you must test a lookahead for each characters. The second pattern use only greedy quantifiers (and possessive) and must test a lookahead only if a space or the first letter of "wrongword" is encountered. The first pattern is only illustrative and use lazy quantifiers (and must test for each characters too)

Comment: @OGHaza: I have forgotten the `\Bw` in the first pattern.

Answer (score 2):

See [this example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/21U).

The regex used is

```
/firstword((?!wrongword).)*lastword/i
```

Answer (score 1):

What if the forbidden word happens to be part of a longer word?  For example, what if you want strings that start with "first" and end with "last" but don't contain the word "word"?  For example:

```
"first one two word last"              # don't match
"first three wordplay four last"       # OK
"first five swordfish six seven last"  # OK
```

Adapting the accepted answer would give you this:

```
/^first (?:(?!word).)+ last$/i
```

...but that would reject all three strings.  There's no need to perform the lookahead at every position anyway.  Just do it once at the beginning of each word:

```
/^first(?:\s+(?!word\b)\w+)*\s+last$/i
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/rG0jY2)